# How to avoid namespace collisions/pollution in a script meant to be sourced?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I want to implement a script `foo.sh` that culminates in the an execution of a command `bar` (with some arguments).  The command `bar` modifies the current shell environment, which means that `foo.sh` must be sourced<sup>1</sup>.  (BTW, the implementation of `bar` is entirely outside my control.)

The purpose of most of the code in `foo.sh` is to compute the arguments that will be passed to `bar`.

In order to keep `foo.sh` reasonably legible/maintainable, I find that I must define many auxiliary variables.  Unfortunately, this sets the stage for

1. namespace collisions (i.e. clobbering existing parameters)
2. namespace pollution (i.e. cluttering the environment with superfluous parameters)

One possible way to avoid, or at least mitigate, these problems is to put most of `foo.sh`'s code into a function (with all its variables declared as `local`) that echoes a suitable string of code to be `eval`'ed within the calling scope; e.g.

```
{
  __messy_calculation () {

      local x y z ...
      local bar_arg_1 bar_arg_2 ...
      ...
      echo "bar $bar_arg_1 bar_arg_2 ..."

  }

  eval "$( __messy_calculation )"

} always {

  unfunction __messy_calculation

}
```

This takes care of the namespace pollution problem, and reduces the namespace collision problem to the one for the name of the function.  (I'm not a big fan of using eval, though.)

I figure that this situation is generic enough that there already exist standard ways to address it.  If so, please let me know.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>In case my reasoning here is flawed, let me just add that if I put all the code, including the call to `bar`, into a function, when I execute this function on the command line the current environment remains unaffected, which renders the function useless.  In contrast, if I source the line that executes the call to `bar`, the current environment is modified as expected.</sup>

Comment: What makes you think you need to use `eval`?  Just call the function.

Comment: You don't even need to define  `__messy_calcuation`; `zsh` supports anonymous functions: `function { local x y z; local bar_arg_1 ...; ...; bar $bar_arg_1 $bar_arg_2; }`

Answer (score 4):

For variables it is possible to use an anonymous function (as noted in the comment above).  That means you can can define as many variables as you want.  The ones you want to hide from the caller you prefix with `local`, the ones you want to communicate to the caller you just define normally:

```
function {
  local my_var=foo
  your_var=bar
  : ...
}
```

But for functions that will not work as they can not be declared `local`.  I had this problem in my [zshrc](https://github.com/lucc/shell-config/blob/master/zshrc) and decided to prefix all names of my "local" functions with a short string (like you do namespaces in C) and to do a wildcard `unfunction` at the end:

```
function foo-do-something () {
  : ...
}
function foo-do-some-more-stuff () {
  : ...
}
function foo-main () {
  local my_var=oof
  you_var=rab
  foo-do-something for bar
  foo-do-some-more-stuff with baz
}
foo-main
unfunction -m 'foo-*'
```

This is not an optimal solution in my opinion (I would prefer local functions) but it works for me.

Comment: For Bash `unset -f <name>` will do the trick. If namespaced functions are used then this line will unset all of them `unset -f $(compgen -A function <prefix>)`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is using  subshells, nested functions and `unset` for the main func:

```bsh
my_app_main()
(
  unset -f my_app_main

  a()
  (
    x=1
    echo "a.x is $x"
  )

  b()
  (
    x=2
    echo "b.x is $x"
  )

  c()
  (
    echo "c.x is $x (empty)"
  )

  a
  b
  c
)

my_app_main "$@"

echo "$x (empty - x is gone)"

# all gone
type my_app_main a b c
```

Comment: Why do `a`, `b`, and `c` vanish despite not being declared `local`?

Comment: Because my_app_main body is enclosed with () instead of {}.